# How to say emojis in Chinese?

Tags: translation

We have tried different translators with no luck. Is there any translation to Chinese? Do we have to write the English version like Sim Card?

These are emojis:

[image: emojis]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use `emoji` directly. And it's usually translated as [绘文字](https://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-cn/%E7%B9%AA%E6%96%87%E5%AD%97) (from the Japanese `絵文字`).

You can also call them as `emoji表情`, or `表情符号`/`表情图标` for more general intent.

Comment: All answers seem correct. I have chosen 表情符号 (simplified Chinese). Thanks you all! :)

Answer (score 4):

Google translates 'emoji' as 表情符號, I think it is an acceptable translation.

The term Emoji originated from 絵文字 in Japanese. Since Japanese Kanji came from Chinese characters, 絵文字 can be reverse import back to Chinese. Which mean if you say 絵文字 in Chinese, people would know you are talking about emojis.

- *Emojis is different from 顏文字 , which you make faces with typed characters.*

Examples of 顏文字:

[image]

Comment: Yes, it sounds right to me too. I've always used and heard 表情 only, omitting the 符号. I guess for colloquial speech and provided the context is unambiguous 表情 is enough.

Answer (score 3):

Most people say "emoji" without translating. While many use "颜文字" for "emoticon" (from Japanese 顔文字 *kao-moji*), we almost never really say "绘文字". A semantical translation might be "表情图" ("graphical emotions"), but it's not really equivalent to "emoji". So, you could just use "emoji" as is.

Answer (score 2):

### 表情符號

表情符號 is the best translation for the type of emoji mentioned.

Or, you can directly use the English word **emoji** orally or in informal writing.

Side note: Japanese style emoji `(´・ω・｀) ('・ω・´) (*´ω｀*)` are usually referred as [顔文字](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E9%A1%94%E6%96%87%E5%AD%97).

---

### Reference

[iOS 10.2 release note (Chinese)](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1893?viewlocale=zh_TW):

> iOS 10.2 [...] 加入了超過 100 種新的**表情符號**，其中包含新的表情、食物、動物、運動和職業。

[iOS 10.2 release note (English)](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1893?viewlocale=en_US):

> iOS 10.2 [...] **Emoji** have been beautifully redesigned to reveal even more detail and over 100 new **emoji** have been added including new faces, food, animals, sports, and professions.

iOS screenshot ([credit](https://briian.com/9598/)):
[image: iOS emoji keyboard]

Comment: I'm glad to read that because that's the translation I have chosen. However, I have picked the Chinese simplified version: 表情符号

Comment: @chelder glad to hear that :) while, choosing Simplified / Traditional Chinese depends on your situation / target audience. it should be consistent (throughout the paragraph / website / app).